# difficulty proving this theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Let $x = s + t$ and $y= s - t$.  For any $f(x, y)$, let us define this function in terms of s and t in the usual fashion: $g(s, t): = f(x(s, t), y(s, t))$.  Show that 
$$ \left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\right)^2 - \left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 = \left(\frac {\partial g} {\partial s}\right) \left( \frac {\partial g} {\partial t}\right) $$

Having a little trouble figuring this problem out.  I've tried a few things, like finding the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ in terms of $g_s, g_t, s_x, s_y, t_x,$ and $t_y$, but nothing quite cancels out for me to prove the result on the right-hand side.  Any thoughts/guidance on how to approach this?

Comment: Some of the experts here may correct me. I don't think that the sign $:=$ is really a used one right? A $=$ should suffice. Am I wrong?

Comment: This was my first time seeing it as well (transcribed from the homework).  I checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), and here's the relevant remark: "x := y, y =: x or x ≡ y means x is defined to be another name for y, under certain assumptions taken in context."  I'm guessing as you said an = alone should generally suffice, although := and =: are taken to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is actually not that difficult. Start from the right side, you will notice that
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$
Do you know how to write the derivative of a composite function right?
Then
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$
Now multipliy the two and you will get the left term, remembering that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

**EDIT:** you write for any function... Of course it should be for any function for which you can calculate the derivatives...

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't take into consideration manipulating the right-hand side initially to obtain the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You define $g$ as a composite function, so it kind of make sense to start from there. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the RHS of the result you are trying to show, in particular let's look at the first term $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial s}$. This partial derivative denotes the change in the function $g$ when $s$ is varied and $t$ is held constant. How does $g$ depend on the variable $s$? It depends on it *through* the relations $x(s,t)$ and $y(s,t)$ since $g(s,t) = f(x(s,t), y(s,t))$. Thus, the partial derivative in question has two terms, corresponding to the effect changing $s$ has on both $x$ and $y$, and the resulting effect of the changes in $x$ and $y$ on $f$:

$ \left(\frac{\partial g(s,t)}{\partial s}\right)_t = \left(\frac{\partial f(x(s,t), y(s,t))}{\partial s}\right)_t = \left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)_y \left(\frac{\partial x(s,t)}{\partial t}\right)_s + \left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)_x \left(\frac{\partial y(s,t)}{\partial s}\right)_t $

$=  \left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)_y  + \left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)_x $

where the subscripts denote the variable being held constant with each partial derivative. This is a multidimensional chain rule, which you should be able to prove from the definitions of partial derivatives, if you so desire. The last line follows from the definitions $x = s + t$ and $y = s - t$ so that the partial derivative of each of these with $s$ at constant $t$ is just 1. If you perform a similar computation for  $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$, and take the product indicated on the RHS of your original equation, you should get the desired result.